# mysql: special use of concat

Tags: mysql, concatenation

I have table A and B with many to one associations (b contains fk_a). Let's assume the sample tables are as follows:

A:

```
id first 
1  sample
2  sample
```

B:

```
id fk_a  type value
1  1      som  thing
2  1      oth  other
3  2      som  thing
4  2      oth  any
```

I would like the "first" column in table A to be unique, and I would like to achieve it by having to:

desired A:

```
id first 
1  sample-thing-other
2  sample-thing-any
```

Is it possible to use pure MYSQL to use UPDATE and CONCAT on table A to obtain desired update?

It would be easy if I had everything in one table, I could just write

```
UPDATE A 
SET first = CONCAT(first, value)
```

but unfortunately I have many-to-one association and I am not sure if it is even possible in such case.

Comment: What is the actual use case? The id field on A means that you shouldn't need to make the other values unique in order for them to be useful. That's the point of using relational tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not have the instance of mysql, and not test it. use the [group_concat](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)

```
UPDATE A, (SELECT fk_a, GROUP_CONCAT(value SEPARATOR '-') as concat_value FROM B GROUP BY fk_a) AS t

SET A.first = CONCAT(A.first, '-', t.concat_value) 

WHERE A.id = t.fk_a;
```

Comment: I wll test it but even if there is a typo I guess this is exactly what I need

Answer (score 1):

[Group_Concat](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) is your friend.

But may I remind you of first normal form?